# Adding guest user in Active Directory that are from an on-premise Active Directory

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

When adding a user as a guest user in our Active Directory they get the following error:

> "You have been invited to [Active Directory] application as
>   [user@domain].
>
> However, we are not able to create this work or school account because
>   [domain] is a domain that is federated with your on-premises AD.
>
> Please contact your admin to ensure you are properly configured in
>   your on-premise AD and you can re-attempt to accept this invite"

What is going on here?
And is it possible to change some setting somewhere that allows the user to be added?

Comment: Do you mean can't add guest user to Azure AD?

Comment: I added a guest user and then the user got this error message when trying to accept the invitation

Comment: I'm not sure. I created the AD from the Azure portal (I'm not sure if there are different types). I don't have control/access to the other AD, so I'm not sure about the detail there. I then tried to add the user from the Azure portal by going to Azure Active Directory -> Users and groups -> All users -> New guest user, and then I just entered the user's email address.

Comment: Does this user account store in Azure active directory(cloud)?

Comment: Do you want to invite an external user to your Azure active directory? Your azure active directory is federated with your on-premises AD?

Comment: I'm trying to add an external user to my AD (domain1), the external user (user@domain2). My AD (domain1) is not an on-premise AD, but I'm pretty sure that domain2 is.

Comment: According to the official article, external user's admin must sync the user's account to Azure Active Directory then this user should be able to accept the invitation. here a similar case about you, please refer to it. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d67bc4e3-0339-4fed-9eed-0adbd1fcf3ef/errors-when-inviting-users-with-azure-b2b-collaboration-preview?forum=WindowsAzureAD

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you are add an external user to your Azure AD, **user domain is federated**.
By default, if the user invited is not present in the cloud in the organization, Azure will try to create the user.

If user domain is federated, Azure don’t have to permission to create the user.
Should contact user's administrator to sync user's identity to Azure.

> External user does not exist already in a federated domain
>
> If you are using federation authentication and the user does not
>   already exist in Azure Active Directory, the user cannot be invited.
>   To resolve this issue, the external user’s admin must synchronize the
>   user’s account to Azure Active Directory.

More information about invite external user to Azure AD, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-b2b-troubleshooting#the-user-that-i-invited-is-receiving-an-error-during-redemption).

Comment: As I understand it, my AD is not federated. It's only domain name is [domain1].onmicrosoft.com. Also it's not on-premise.

Does this answer still apply then? I think that the AD that the external user is already in is both on-premise and federated.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, not your domain, user's domain use federated. I will update my answer:)

Comment: @hAxel maybe we should make sure does this user's domain is federated.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :) I'm still a bit confused though. In the documentation that you referred to, it sounds like it's referring to the case where the user I'm trying to invite does not exist in the other AD. I don't think that is the case here.
Is the AD federated if its users don't have the format user@xxx.onmicrosoft.com?

Comment: @hAxel Base on my knowledge, invite user to your Azure AD, just create a account in your AAD, will not sync password and other information to AAD. For now, not all domain be trust with AAD, so we should sync user's identity to AAD, after that we can invite this user to your AAD.

Comment: @hAxel Just want to confirm the current situations. does this work for you?

Comment: I've dropped the issue since I don't have access to the customers AD. We chose to create other users instead.